# Clonezilla multiple seperate images to single hdd

Tags: images, clone, clonezilla

Hi I'm having trouble finding if this is possible. 
I want to clone multiple different types of computers and save each one to a single massive hdd. So I can consolidate(save money)  and not have a hdd for each computer cloned. 
Thanks in advance! 
-David

Answer (score 0):

We put Clonezilla on a bootable USB HD.  When we boot, we mount an 'IMAGES' folder as the clonezilla root and store all of our images there.  Works quite well.  You could still use Clonezilla from a CD or flash drive, and just use the USB hard drive for image storage, but we wanted it to be a single device for everything.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this! Does it keep the mbr, etc?

Comment: Yes, if you image the whole disk (as opposed to a single partition).  You'll select "Device->Image" work (not device->device), then save the whole disk.